# Merging Objects with Immutable js

Tags: javascript, object, immutability, redux, immutable.js

I am using React, Redux & Immutable here. The question is regarding merging a plain Js object into Immutable `Map` obj.

Importing Immutable.js:

```
import { List as iList,
         Map as iMap } from "immutable";
```

`action.payload` is this:

```
{
    Preview : {
        tabClass : "tabPreview tab activeTab"
    },
    Body : {
        tabClass : "tabBody tab"
    },
    Sleeve : {
        tabClass : "tabSleeve tab"
    }
};
```

`InitialTabState` created with 'Immutable.js' is this:

```
const initialTabState = iList.of(
    iMap({
        tabClass : "tabPreview tab activeTab",
        tabName : "Preview"
    }),
    iMap({
        tabClass : "tabBody tab",
        tabName : "Body"
    }),
    iMap({
        tabClass : "tabSleeve tab",
        tabName : "Sleeve"
    })
);
```

The reducer function, which is merging the `action.payload` at the top, into the `InitialTabState` above is this:

```
const tabsState = ( state = initialTabState, action ) => {
    let payload = action.payload;
    switch( action.type ) {
    case( ENABLE_TAB ):
        return (
            state.map( (obj) => {
                let curObjName = obj.get( "tabName" );
                return (
                    obj.merge( payload[ curObjName ][ "tabName" ] )
                );
            })
        );
    ...
};
```

However, nothing seems to be happening. I do not get any error, the output object remains the same as InitialTabState, when the property `tabClass` within it should change as per the merge function from Immutable.js.

Comment: What do you expect the state to look like when it returns from the reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.merge( payload[ curObjName ][ "tabName" ] )` merging a property that doesn't exist on the payload. I believe you want `obj.merge( payload[ curObjName ])`, which will update the tab's classes.